# DataFrame condition on multiple values python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to drop some lines from dataframe with python , based on multiple values

```
Code Names Country
1      a    France
2      b    France
3      c    USA
4      d    Canada
5      e    TOTO
6      f    TITI
7      g    Corona
```

I need to have this

```
Code Names Country
1      a    France
4      d    Canada
5      e    TOTO
7      g    Corona
```

I do this :

```
df.drop(df[('f','b','c')in df['names']].index)
```

But it doesnt work : KeyError: False

it works for only one key like this :  df.drop(df['f' in df['names']].index)

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Just , isin and inverse`output = df[~df['Names'].isin(['f','b','c'])].copy()` ? I dont hink you need the drop here , boolean indexing is enough

Comment: @ankyy "isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given "

Comment: Can you post the `isin` code you are trying. Looks like something is off

Answer (score 1):

To remove rows of certain values:

```
indexNames = df[df['Names'].isin(['f', 'b', 'c'])].index
df.drop(indexNames, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Code Names Country
0     1     a  France
3     4     d  Canada
4     5     e    TOTO
6     7     g  Corona
```

Comment: Thanks but they are not really the same, so duplicated won't work :(

Comment: Did this work? If yes, Mark this as the answer and close it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I think this may be what you are looking for.

```
new_df = df.loc[~df.Names.isin(['f','b','c'])].copy()
new_df
```

Output:

```
    Code    Names   Country
0   1       a       France
3   4       d       Canada
4   5       e       TOTO
6   7       g       Corona
```

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, we can use `.drop()` function to drop column and rows.

For dropping specific rows, we need to use `axis = 0`

So your required output can be achieved by following line of code :

```
df4.drop([1,2,5], axis=0)
```

The output will be :

```
code    Names   Country
1        a      France
4        d      Canada
5        e      TOTO
7        g      Corona
```

Comment: I can't use isnin i have this error : isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were give  , Any other suggestions ?